# Automate "Press enter to continue" in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell

I have a script that reads few inputs and waits for user to press ENTER key to continue. Once it continues it again asks for user inputs. Is there a way I can automate the user inputs? I mean by giving the inputs in a file?

I tried redirecting from input file. The "enter key" is causing some confusions. I have gone through the other threads and doesn't help me.

**SCRIPT**
/*******

```
#!/bin/bash
read inputOne
read inputTwo
echo $inputOne
echo $inputTwo
echo "-------------------------"
echo "Press ENTER"
echo "Continue ....."
read inputThree
echo $inputThree
```

*******/

**INPUT FILE**

```
inputOne
inputTwo
inputThree
```

**USAGE**

```
$script.sh < inputfile.txt
```

I am not seeing the 3rd echo getting printed.

Comment: Please paste your code and also input file contents

Comment: added the script and input files

Comment: What about adding that to a shell function?

Comment: In one word: [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)